# 2012 Mini Cooper Diesel

Tags: smoke, mini-cooper

I took my car in for an oil and filter change. Following this my car has now started to spew white smoke from the exhaust that smells like what I can only describe as burning rubber.

I took it back to garage, second filter and oil change was completed and the garage tried to force a regen on the dpf 3 times however this did not clear it.

The garage said they didn’t want to start pulling my engine apart as there is no warning lights and all the levels are fine when checked.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Welcome to the site. There's a few things it could be, but if their best idea is to do another oil change then you need to take it to a better mechanic.